# Emit value then wait for duration before next emission

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm making an 'alert' service. When a new alert comes in, I want to show an alert for a duration. During this duration, I don't want to show other alerts that may have come in. I only want to move to the next alert AFTER the current one is done. So essentially I want to emit the value then wait a duration before emitting the next value.

This can be represented like:

```js
const incomingAlerts$ = interval(1000);

const alerts$ = incomingAlerts$.pipe(
  concatMap((alert) => alert.pipe(delay(3500)))
);
```

This is close to what I want, but delay waits BEFORE emitting the value. Is there an operator or possible set up that will emit the value then wait before emitting the next value (if there is one)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved with `exhaustMap`:

```js
incomingAlerts$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(
    alert => NEVER
      .pipe(
        startWith(startAlertAction(alert)),
        takeUntil(duration),
        endWith(stopAlertAction(alert))
    )
  )
)
```

With `exhaustMap`, an new inner observable won't be created unless the current inner observable becomes inactive(e.g `completes`/emits an `error` notification). If an inner observable is already active, then the value from the outer observable will be ignored.

Comment: Yes but I don't want those values that come to be ignored. I want to "queue" them up essentially to be emitted after some time

Comment: @AveryFerrante what if you replace exhaustMap with concatMap in my example?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a stream that emits a value, waits some amount of time, and then completes.

Here's a kinda weird way of doing that. You set a `timer` and `filter` out its emission. Now you have a stream that emits nothing and completes in 3500ms. You then `startWith` your alert. You can let `concatMap` handle the rest (It will buffer values until the `timer` stream completes):

```
const alerts$ = incomingAlerts$.pipe(
  concatMap(alert => timer(3500).pipe(
    filter(_ => false),
    startWith(alert)
  ))
);
```